# What is the right way to embed categorical data for binary classification task

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

I wan to use a simple feed forward network in Keras. Some of my data values are categories which I want to embed before I'm feeding it to the network.

With the following example data:

```
+-------------+---------+
|category_val | Numeric |
+-------------+---------+
|"A"          | 0.5     |
+-------------+---------+
|"B"          | 0.2     |
+-------------+---------+
|"C"          | 0.1     |
+-------------+---------+
```

I used pandas.get_dummies on the category_val column and got:

```
+---+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| id| category=A| category=B| category=C|
+---+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|  0|          1|          0|          0|
|  1|          0|          1|          0|
|  2|          0|          0|          1|
+---+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Does that mean my input layer should have 4 input features (3 for the generated hot vector and one for the numeric value)?

Like SO:
[image]

It seems easier to just change the category to a number IE: A=1, B=2, C=3 and then have just 2 features, what is the right way and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does that mean my input layer should have 4 input features (3 for the generated hot vector and one for the numeric value)?

**Yes**. This means that the input layer has **4 features**.

> It seems easier to just change the category to a number IE: A=1, B=2, C=3 and then have just 2 features, what is the right way and why?

It is easier  to change `A=1, B=2, C=3`. However it tells the neural network that `C` is somehow greater than `B` which is somehow greater than `A`. To understand the problem with this, let us assume that your `Category` was actually color of an object. Treating colors as numbers will imply that either `red` is greater than `blue` or `blue` is greater than `red`, which is highly unintiutive. We know that neural networks are just concatenated mathematical functions, they will treat colors that are assigned bigger numbers as *bigger colors*, so it is a wrong approach to assign numbers to colors. Therefore, it makes sense to represent each of the color by a separate feature. It helps to think of these **0's** and **1's**  as probabilities related to each feature value. For example value of `red` being 1 indicates that the probability that this object is `red` is 1. Value of 0 indicates 0 probability.

Comment: thank you for the excellent explanation, so ... for each categorial feature I will need to extract one hot vector right?

Comment: It was my pleasure to help. If there is 1 categorical feature and it has 3 unique values then after one hot encoding you will have 3 input features. This way 1 categorical feature gets converted into 3 resultant input features.

Comment: Also, yes if you are using the term ***one-hot vector*** then you can think about it like this. _Each categorical feature will get converted into 1_ ***one-hot vector***. Where the resultant ***one-hot vector*** has 3 values, two 0's and a 1 indicating the value of the feature.

Comment: Well explained!